# time data '0:00:00' does not match format '%H:%M:%S.%f' in python

Tags: python

I have one function that returns time taken in execution.
format= '%H:%M:%S.%f'

```
obj = datatime.strptime(timediffstr, format)
```

sometime value of timediffstr is '0:00:00' in that case above line fails.

How to handle this case?

Answer (score 1):

If the format matches most of the time and you just want to catch the cases where it doesn't and try the second format:

```
from datetime import datetime

timediffstr = '0:00:00'

try:
    result = datetime.strptime(timediffstr, '%H:%M:%S.%f')
except ValueError:
    result = datetime.strptime(timediffstr, '%H:%M:%S')

print(result.time())
```

Answer (score 0):

The other post already answered your question. But if you are ok to use third party libraries you can use  [`dateutil.parser`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html) which is a *date/time string parser which will able to parse most known formats to represent a date and/or time.*.This means you don't have to explicitly mention the *format*.

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> parse(timediffstr)
```